# How to read hidden input from terminal and pipe it to another command

Tags: linux, shell, gnupg, privacy

I would like to be able securely type text in terminal and pipe it to another command to:

- Not be recorded in terminal history
- Be hidden as you type it
- Not be recorded in any file or environmental variable
- Be in memory for shortest possible time

Ideally:

- Using commonly installed tools on linux
- Easy to use as `echo`
- Not having to create any scripts/files
- Can be piped to other commands

Example of non secure input

```
echo "secret" | wc -c
```

Almost what I want:

```
read -s | wc -c
```

Basically the same way how you input password to `sudo` and similar.

My use case

```
echo "secret" | gpg --encrypt --armor -r 1234567890ABCDEF | xclip
```

I am looking for a way with restrictions I mentioned in points above. Knowing that what I am looking for doesn't exist is also an answer I will accept and mark.

I created alias from accepted answer

```
alias secnote="{ read -s; printf %s $REPLY; } | gpg --encrypt --armor -r 123467890ABCDEF | pbcopy"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you wanted to achieve ?

```
$ read -s       # I type `secret`
$ echo $REPLY
secret
$ printf %s $REPLY | wc -c
6
$ unset REPLY
$ echo $REPLY
# empty now
```

Or you want one-liner like this :

```
{ read -s -p "Input a secret: "; printf %s $REPLY; } | wc -c
```

If you define an alias :

```
alias readp='{ read -s -p "Input a secret: "; printf %s $REPLY; }'
```

then you can do `readp | wc -c`

Comment: Well I know `read` stores the reply in environmental variable and I also know environmental variables can be printed and cleared. That is why I explicitly mentioned it to nudge answers in direction where they are not used. I don't require `read` to be used either it was just closest command I found. I would like one liner simple as using `echo` if possible. Knowing what I am asking is not possible is also an answer I would accept and mark. I'll try to update my question to make it clearer what I want.

Comment: Except for not being very keyboard friendly its what I want, thank you. Still I find it weird that `read` doesn't support piping its output.